# How do I enable Data API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am attempting to connect to my relational database on aws so I can create tables and the likes.

[image]

When I click Action then Query, and fill out the form with the correct information, I get the following.

[image]

How do I "enable Data API?"

Comment: Which database are you using exactly?

Comment: @Marcin Aurora PostgreSQL, serverless, I'm trying to follow this: https://betterprogramming.pub/build-mobile-serverless-apps-using-amazon-aurora-amplify-and-swiftui-7562ecb7df9a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable Data API using in your RDS console's Connectivity section for your postgresql and modify existing database to enable the API:

[image]

More in [Enabling the Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/data-api.html#data-api.enabling).

Answer (score 0):

Found the part of the tutorial that covers it.
[image]